# CSS, vertical alignment doesn't correctly work in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, cross-browser, vertical-alignment

I am trying to create a page that has fixed height Header and also footer (=Nav), where there in between of them is a contentWrapper div, that fully stretches to fill the maximum height of the screen. In the contentWrapper, there is a content div, that includes a form. I need this content div to be **both vertically and horizontally aligned according to its parent div contentWrapper**. I found a solution for this, which works pretty well, but only in Chrome and IE, *not in Firefox (version 22.0)*.

I created this fiddle where you can observe this behaviour, try different browsers.
http://jsfiddle.net/qWYqb/

Any ideas how to fix this for Mozilla Firefox?

HTML:

```
<div id="pageWrapper">
            <header>
                <div id="logo">
                    Logo
                </div>        
            </header>
            <div id="contentWrapper">
                <div class="valignMiddle">
                    <div id="content">
                        <form>
                            <table>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><label for="fullName">Full Name</label></td>
                                        <td><input id="fullName" type="text" name="fullName" required="required" /></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><label for="email">E-mail</label></td>
                                        <td><input id="email" type="email" name="email" required="required" /></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                            <div>
                                <input type="submit" id="submit-go" value="Start Now"/>  
                            </div>                
                        </form>  
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <nav>    
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" class="btn1">Option1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="btn2">Option2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
```

CSS

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    outline:none;
}
html, body{
    min-height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

table
{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

td, th {
    vertical-align:top;
}

body{
    background-color: #E3E3E3;
}
/* This padding is there to stop margin collapsing */
div {
    padding: 1px 0;
}

#pageWrapper{
    position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; left:0; right:0;
    padding: 126px 0 100px 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 400px;
    overflow: hidden
}

/* --- HEADER --- */
header{ 
    width: 100%;
    height: 126px;
    margin-top:-126px;
    background: yellow;
}

/* --- MAIN CONTENT --- */
#contentWrapper{
    width: 100%;
    position: static; 
    display: table; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    min-height: 100%;
    background: red;
}

.valignMiddle { 
    position: static; 
    display: table-cell; 
    vertical-align: middle; 
    width: 100%; 
}

#content{
    width: 293px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: green;
}

/* --- NAVIGATION --- */
nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    margin-bottom:-100px;
    background: pink;
}

nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none outside none;
}

nav ul {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at working demo here: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qWYqb/1/)

```
#contentWrapper{
    width: 100%;
    position: static; 
    display: table; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
}
```

This is working fine in Firefox . Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: This works, thank you! Only I found another cross-browser compatibility issue. This this solution doesn't work for older IE versions (tried on IE8). In older IE everything get aligned to the left side. Even inline alignment of li doesn't work. Any idea how to fix this?